# Umbraco & Razor: If CurrentPage/Model is a Child, condition

Tags: razor, umbraco

My navigation/node structure is as follows:

Home
--About us
--Our Services
-----Finance
-----Insurance

My current code loops through the nodes and lists them in an . When the 'CurrentPage' has children, the menu includes the children.

The problem with this loop is that when one of those children (Finance or Insurance) is the 'CurrentPage', the 'if' condition on 'Our Services' node fails as th CurrentPage no longer has children, therefore 'Finance' and 'Insurance' now longer remain in the menu.

I want to add to me 'if', an '||' clause which would basically say 'or CurrentPage is a child node'

Code below
thanks

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var page in @CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1).Children)
    {
        <li class="menuItems @(page.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "selected" : null)">
            <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name test</a>
        </li>


        if (@CurrentPage.Children.Count() > 0)
        {                
            foreach (var childPage in page.Children)
            {                    
                <li class="menuItems menuChildItems @(childPage.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "selected" : null)">
                    <a href="@childPage.Url">@childPage.Name</a>
                </li>
            }
        }

    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first foreach should be from your Home. (Is your Home at level 1?)
2. There is no need to do the if(has children) check, because if there isn't any children, it will not loop.

Do you only want 2 levels of menus? If so, do it like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var page in CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1).Children)
    {
        <li class="menuItems @(page.Id == CurrentPage.Id ? "selected" : "")">
            <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name test</a>
        </li>

        @if(CurrentPage.Id == page.Id || CurrentPage.Parent.Id == page.Id)
        {
            foreach (var childPage in page.Children)
            {                    
                <li class="menuItems menuChildItems @(childPage.Id == CurrentPage.Id ? "selected" : "")">
                    <a href="@childPage.Url">@childPage.Name</a>
                </li>
            }
        }
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello, Yes Home is level 1. With you code, the subpages at level 3 will appear at all times. I only want them to appear when the parent is selected. thanks

Comment: Hello, not it doesn't. Finance and Insurance are always visible, unless you specify the 'if', which is where we run into the same problem. Your code above is basically refactoring mine, minus the if condition. Cheers

Comment: Okay cool I didnt understand that. I will update my answer.. But remember, for SEO reasons, you should hide these with css instead.

Comment: Im not sure if this is what you want. But now childpages will be visible if you are on the parent page, or if you are on one of the child pages which have a current page

Comment: Thanks again. The if statement now shows an error 'the expression cannot be used as an assignment target'. Also itellisense doesn't recognise ...Parent.ID

Comment: Sorry missed an = in CurrentPage.Parent.Id == page.Id

Comment: Should have spotted that myself. 6 week old twin girls == sleep deprivation.. Thanks again for your help